# Fixing some warnings with scanf

Tags: c, warnings, scanf

```
int stringCheck(char*);

void compile(int *instructionSet2, int *accumulator2, int *instructionCounter2, int *instructionRegister2, int *operationCode2, int *operand2)
{

    char *readIn;
    readIn = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*11);

    while(fgets(readIn,11,stdin) != NULL)
    {
        *instructionCounter2 = scanf("%d",(int*)readIn);
        instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] = (stringCheck((char*)scanf("%s",readIn)));
        instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] += (scanf("%d",(int*)readIn));
    }
}

int stringCheck(char *stIn)
{
    if (strcmp(stIn,"READ") == 0)
    {
        return 10 * 100;
    } /* Snipped to just give an idea of the numeric value assignment for words read. */
}
```

Alright, what I'm trying to do here is figure out how to properly read in a set of instructions like this:

```
00 READ 9
01 READ 10
02 LOAD 9
03 SUB 10
04 BRNG 7
05 WRIT 9
06 HALT 99
07 WRIT 10
08 HALT 99
09 SET 0
10 SET 0
```

I've gotten myself a little stuck though on trying to read in the words. Basically, I just want to scan in an int, a string, and then another int and continue doing this while the end of file isn't reached.

It turns out that scanf returns the number of characters successfully read instead of pointers so the second line inside the while loop is warning me of that when compiling.

I'm trying to fix this warning in particular:

```
virtualcomp.c:66:56: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Points to this line specifically:

```
instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] = (stringCheck((char*)scanf("%s",readIn)));
```

How can I fix this?

**NOTE:** I'm trying to avoid putting in more variables, only using the ones present.

Comment: Stop writing casts in your code. They tell the compiler "Even though I'm doing this illegal/dangerous operation, I know what I'm doing so let me do it".  On the `malloc` line the dangerous operation is failing to `#include <stdlib.h>`. On the line you quote, the dangerous operation is passing an `int` to a function that expects a character string.  The data that `scanf` reads goes into the `readIn` variable. The return value of `scanf` is an integer that tells you whether it succeeded or failed; read the documentation for `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse all three variables with one `scanf` call. Note `scanf` returns the number of input variables assigned. I think you need something like this:

```
int n1, n2;
char buf[12];
...
...
sscanf(readIn, "%d %s %d",&n1, buff, &n2);

*instructionCounter2 = n1;
instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] = stringCheck(buff);
instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] += n2;
```

Comment: Think I should probably do that for the other two as well, just to be safe?

Comment: Sorry I was busy mid-edits. Try that and if it's useful please upvote thanks.

Comment: Actually, the whole point was to avoid introducing extra variables such as n1 and n2.

Comment: Using sscanf you will need storage for the values read. The other way is to parse the lines - is that what you are trying to do in stringCheck?

Comment: It's what the char *readIn is for, storing the string. readIn is then sent off to stringCheck which will return an integer value based upon what it matches it up to be, i.e. READ = 1000, WRIT = 1100, etc. Also, the memory must be dynamically allocated for the readIn, hence why I used malloc. The max length of the instruction set is 11. EDIT: Now that I think about it I could just use sscanf to read directly into those three parts...

Comment: an use of additional two integer variables of limited scope is not a crime.

Comment: Your first original post was all that I needed actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying to to an `int` into a generic buffer (of size 11) is unorthodox.

```
char *readIn;
readIn = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
...
*instructionCounter2 = scanf("%d",(int*)readIn);
```

Suggest instead dropping the `malloc()` and reading directly into the 2 `int`.

```
char s[11];
char readIn[21 + sizeof s + 21 + 2];  // 21 is chars in a 64-bit int
while(fgets(readIn, sizeof readIn, stdin) != NULL)
{
   int n;
   if (sscanf(readIn, "%d%n", instructionCounter2, &n) != 1 || 
       sscanf(&readIn[n], "%11s%d",s,&instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] != 2)
     Handle_SyntaxError();
   instructionSet2[*instructionCounter2] += stringCheck(s);
}
```

Note: a more robust solution would assess the value of `instructionCounter2` before using as an array index.

Comment: I cannot introduce any variables outside what I've shown in my own code. The challenge of this program is to use only what we have been allowed. The compile function is an exception, where we are allowed to introduce one string to read in the rest.

Comment: @Major Cooke  To save time on your part and ours, suggest if the requirements are "cannot introduce any variables outside what I've shown in my own code", post that rather than the more lenient "trying to avoid putting in more variables".  All-in-all, these restrictions preclude "how to properly read in a set of instructions".